# Intellij 12 plugin loading

Tags: intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ 12 #IU-123.72 in a secured environment i.e, cannot directly install plugins.

The installation looks for plugins under C:\Users\username.IntelliJIdea12\config\plugins I have a downloaded version of the python plugin as a zip and I unzip the contents in the plugins folder.

This does not however bring the python plugin on board. File -> Settings -> Plugins does not show python.

What am I missing?

Comment: 1) Did you restart IntelliJ? 2) I see that at my environment Python also requires that the following bundled plugins are enabled: "Remote Hosts Access", "Remove Run", "Yaml", "Coverage" - try to enable them as well before you restart

Comment: "Remote Hosts Access", "Remote Run", "Yaml", "Coverage" are all enabled and restart is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Update to 12.0.4](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) and use the <kbd>Install plugin from disk...</kbd> button. Pay attention to the compatibility. IDEA 12.0.x compatible Python plug-in [can be downloaded here](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/download?pr=idea&updateId=12224).

The latest plug-in version [available in the repository](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=631) is designed for [IDEA 12.1 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12.1+EAP).

Comment: It is going to take me a while to get an update. How can I confirm that there is an error? Ideally I would like to see an error log and then upgrade? Where would I see the error when IDEA loads plugins

Comment: The log can be found using `Help` | `Reveal Log in ...`, see also [this FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181).

Comment: The log does not indicate anything about "Attempted to load plugin XXX and failed". Infact there is absolutely no information on what the plugin status is. Can you please help?

Comment: Contact support with the log, IDEA version and plug-in file version that you are trying to install.

Comment: Actually your link http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=631 helped me. For my IntelliJ version I downloaded the correct library version and that works for me